# Regex to find a string and Replace it or add extra characters based on a condition

Tags: java, c#, regex

I have a string `{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||to turn}}` when ever a string starts with `{{m` and ends with `}}` i want to surround `to turn` with `()` brackets string which comes before `}}`

**String:**
`{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||to turn}}`

**Required String:**
`{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||(to turn)}}`

the string can be not only `to turn` but any string.

Comment: Try `({{m(?:\|[^\|]+)*\|\|)([^}]+}})` https://regex101.com/r/nBRZeq/1/

Comment: @Thefourthbird it currently returns `(to turn}})` instead of `(to turn)}}`.

Comment: @IldarAkhmetov See this update `({{m(?:\|[^\|]+)*\|\|)([^}]+)(?=}})` https://regex101.com/r/nBRZeq/2

Comment: @Thefourthbird it's a more clever solution than mine, as it has nothing but `\1`, `\2` and the brackets in the substitution pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\{\{m\|[^}]*\|)([^|}]*)(\}\})
```

and the replacement:

```
\1(\2)\3
```

**Input:**

```
{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||to turn}}
{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||abc}}
{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||to turn}},{{m|ine-pro|*gers-||to bend, turn}}
{{do nothing}}
#do nothing
```

**Output:**

```
{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||(to turn)}}
{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||(abc)}}
{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||(to turn)}},{{m|ine-pro|*gers-||(to bend, turn)}}
{{do nothing}}
#do nothing
```

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/yoo9KG/2/

**Explanations:**

- `(\{\{m\|[^}]*\|)` will capture strings that start by `{{m` followed by 0 to N character that are not `}` until reaching a `|`, the last one located in your `{{m...|...|..}}` structure. The capture group can be back referenced via `\1`
- `([^|}]*)` will match the last string in your structure and store it in the 2nd capture group.
- `(\}\})` will capture the last 2 `}` and store it in the 3rd group.
- You use in the replacement the 3 backreferences and you surround the 2nd one by parenthesis to reach your result.

**java code:**

```
String input = "{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||to turn}},{{m|ine-pro|*gers-||to bend, turn}}";
String output = input.replaceAll("(\\{\\{m\\|[^}]*\\|)([^|}]*)(\\}\\})", "$1($2)$3");
System.out.println(output);
```

**output:**

```
{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||(to turn)}},{{m|ine-pro|*gers-||(to bend, turn)}}
```

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS: You are welcome, let me know if you have any question!

Comment: bro how to match everything but two vertical lines `|*karros||wagon}}`

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS: what about `\{\{m\|(?:(?!\|\|).)*`
demo: https://regex101.com/r/yoo9KG/4

Answer (score 3):

You might use 2 capturing groups with a positive lookahead:

```
({{m(?:\|[^\|]+)*\|\|)([^}]+)(?=}})
```

In Java

```
String regex = "(\\{\\{m(?:\\|[^\\|]+)*\\|\\|)([^\\}]+)(?=\\}})";
```

About the pattern

- `(` Capture group 1

  - `{{m` Match literally
  - `(?:\|[^\|]+)*` Repeat 0+ times matching `|` followed by matching not `|`
  - `\|\|` Match ||
- `)` Close group 1
- `(` Capturing group 2

  - `[^}]+` Match 1+ times not }
- `)` Close group 2
- `(?=}})` Positive lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is }}

[Pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/nBRZeq/2)

In the replacement, use the 2 capturing groups:

```
$1($2)
```

For example in C#:

```
string pattern = @"({{m(?:\|[^\|]+)*\|\|)([^}]+)(?=}})";
string input = @"{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||to turn}}";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(input, pattern, @"$1($2)"));
```

Comment: string consists of repetition will it change everything in line ex: `{{m|gem-pro|*karzijan?||to turn}},{{m|ine-pro|*gers-||to bend, turn}}`

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS Yes it will https://regex101.com/r/nBRZeq/3 but in Java or C# you might also choose to replace the first match only.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this regex:

`{{m(.+)\|\|(.+)}}`

and this substitution pattern:

`{{m\1||(\2)}}`

**Working example**: https://regex101.com/r/3inQ3p/1

Comment: can you post the java version of regex ?